# Zoom client is teeny tiny

Tags: 20.10, zoom-meeting

Ubuntu 20.10
Zoom client 5.4.54779.1115
zoom_amd64.deb

When I run the Zoom client the screens are so tiny I can barely read them, the web version works okay (in FF.) Once upon a time I was able to alter a setting in the client but I can no longer find it. Does anyone have this same experience and know how to fix it? Here's a pretty picture of it:
[zoom is the tiny little box in the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43cKA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved my problem using the deductive principle of throw-mud-on-the-wall:
edit home>.config>zoomus.conf, then set  autoScale=true

so far so good